# How can I force Gmail to recognize an ICS file attachment?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

According to the Gmail team, [Google Mail should automatically detect ICS attachments](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+Gmail/posts/5JgrXwUEYFE).

But it doesn't. At least [not for the ICS I got from an iPhone user](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk1x8wed5uvhqbb/Screenshot%202014-03-14%2008.37.09.png):
[image: ICS attachment not recognized by gmail]

How can I make sure these are parsed as ICS attachments by Gmail?

The attachment seems correctly formatted:

```
--Apple-Mail-FBEB8378-1D70-46DA-B281-02503CEA5C67
Content-Type: text/calendar;
    name="Biertje drinken met jeroen.ics"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="Biertje drinken met jeroen.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

BEGIN:VCALENDAR=0D=0ACALSCALE:GREGORIAN=0D=0AVERSION:2.0=0D=0AMETHOD:PUBLISH=
```

Comment: @Vidar I really meant "force" as the update should have made gmail do it automatically. Apparently it doesn't, so some force is needed.

Comment: Sorry about that - I have reinstated the "force".

Comment: May the force be with you @VidarS.Ramdal

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach. Installing [Calify](http://www.califyapp.com) will allow you to open *.ics files in Google Calendar. You will just have to download the file, open it and Calify will open Google Calendar in new browser tab with all the details pre-filled.

Disclaimer: I'm the app author.

Comment: If you can make that a Chrome Extension, I could use it. My main Chrome usage is not on Windows.

Comment: No plans for an Extension for now, but apps for Mac and Linux may be coming in future.